# OSX terminal to split csv file in specific way

Tags: macos, csv, terminal

I've got a massive CSV file (12GB) that i need to extract specific lines from, say all lines that start with a specific number. Is there an easy way to split apart the file using the MAC terminal? Using something like csplit seems like the way forward but I'm a bit of a noob

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) than StackOverflow, as this really isn't a programming question.

Comment: given I want to use the terminal which runs unix i don't realy see why this isn't a programming question, but thanks anyway

Comment: The terminal doesn't "run unix"; Mac OS X is a Unix-like operating system with a `tcsh` shell.  *Using* a Unix shell command does not mean that you're *programming*.  StackExchange has separated the specific concerns to [different sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology).  You can check out what's available related to what you're trying to accomplish: [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).